# Understanding Data Loading and Manipulation in Azure ML Pipeline with PythonScriptStep

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm in the process of adapting my codebase for an Azure ML pipeline and need some assistance understanding certain aspects. I am converting one of my steps into a script and executing it through a [PythonScriptStep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.python_script_step.pythonscriptstep?view=azure-ml-py), but I have a few questions about how data is transferred and managed within the pipeline.

Here's a brief look at an example similar to mmy current pipeline step:

```
# Define pipeline step
from azureml.data import OutputFileDatasetConfig
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep, EstimatorStep

raw_ds = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'raw_dataset')  # initial data

data_store = ws.get_default_datastore()
prepped_data = OutputFileDatasetConfig('prepped')

step1 = PythonScriptStep(name = 'prepare data',
                         source_directory = 'scripts',
                         script_name = 'data_prep.py',
                         compute_target = 'aml-cluster',
                         arguments = ['--raw-ds', raw_ds.as_named_input('raw_data'),
                                      '--out_folder', prepped_data])
```

and the corresponding `data_prep.py` script:

```
# data_prep.py script
from azureml.core import Run
import argparse
import os

run = Run.get_context()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--raw-ds', type=str, dest='raw_dataset_id')
parser.add_argument('--out_folder', type=str, dest='folder')
args = parser.parse_args()
output_folder = args.folder

raw_df = run.input_datasets['raw_data'].to_pandas_dataframe()

prepped_df = raw_df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]

os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, 'prepped_data.csv')
prepped_df.to_csv(output_path)
```

My questions are:

1. Why is it necessary to include command line arguments in `data_prep.py` if I'm already loading the data from the Run context?
2. Is there an alternative method to load the data, which doesn't involve using the context?
3. How should I handle data loading if my data is not in a tabular format, for example, if it's a JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: It is not necessary to include the dataset in arguments, it is all depend on your requirements. You can pass your dataset in `inputs` inside
`PythonScriptStep` function.

```
step1 = PythonScriptStep(
            name = 'prepare data',
            source_directory = 'script',
            script_name = 'data_prep.py',
            compute_target = 'jgscluster',
            arguments = ['--out-folder', prepped_data],
            inputs=[raw_ds.as_named_input("raw_data")],
            runconfig=aml_run_config)
```

Here, instead of giving in arguments you can give it in `inputs`, and same it accessed in script using run context.

2 If you have URI of the input dataset you can use that without `Run`
context.
The sample URI will be like this.

```
azureml://subscriptions/<sub_name>/resourcegroups/<resouce_grp>/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/UI/2023-07-12_064045_UTC/winequality-red.csv
```

Then you can pass this as `path` in arguments and read it in pandas dataframe.

With this you can handle json files also.

```
import  pandas  as  pd
pd.read_json("azureml://subscriptions/<sub_name>/resourcegroups/<resouce_grp>/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<path_to_file>")
pd.read_csv("azureml://subscriptions/<sub_name>/resourcegroups/<resouce_grp>/workspaces/<workspace>/datastores/<datastore_name>/paths/<path_to_file>")
```

Below are the altered code.

```
aml_run_config = RunConfiguration()
aml_run_config.target = "jgscluster"
docker_config = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)
aml_run_config.docker = docker_config
aml_run_config.environment.python.conda_dependencies = CondaDependencies.create(
     conda_packages=['pandas','scikit-learn'],
     pip_packages=['azureml-fsspec','azure-ai-ml'])
     
print("Run configuration created.")
prepped_data = OutputFileDatasetConfig('prepped')

step1 = PythonScriptStep(name = 'prepare data',
    source_directory = 'script',
    script_name = 'data_prep.py',
    compute_target = 'jgscluster',
    arguments = ['--out-folder', prepped_data,
    '--path',csv_path,
    '--path-json',json_path],
    runconfig=aml_run_config)
```

Here, add your datastore URI path in  `csv_path` and `json_path` as shown in above example.
and in `data_prep.py`

```
import argparse
import os
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--out-folder', type=str, dest='folder')
parser.add_argument('--path', type=str, dest='arg_raw_ds')
parser.add_argument('--path-json', type=str, dest='arg_raw_json')

args = parser.parse_args()
output_folder = args.folder
raw_ds_p = args.arg_raw_ds
raw_json_p = args.arg_raw_json
raw_df = pd.read_csv(raw_ds_p)
raw_json = pd.read_json(raw_json_p)

os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, 'prepped_data.csv')
output_path_json = os.path.join(output_folder, 'json_prepped_data.csv')
raw_df.to_csv(output_path)
raw_json.to_csv(output_path_json)
```

[image]

If you want this path dynamically, you use below code to get those paths.

```
import  os
root_datastore = "azureml://subscriptions/<your_sub_id>/resourcegroups/your_resource_group_name/workspaces/<your_ml_workspace>/datastores/<datastore_where_you_uploaded>/paths"
ws = Workspace.from_config()
raw_ds = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'raw_data_wine')
raw_json = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'raw_data_json')
csv_paths=[]
json_paths = []
for  i  in  str(raw_ds).split('\''):
    if  i.endswith('.csv'):
        csv_paths.append(i)
        
for  i  in  str(raw_json).split('\''):
    if  i.endswith('.json'):
        json_paths.append(i)
        
csv_path= os.path.join(root_datastore,csv_paths[0])
json_path=os.path.join(root_datastore,json_paths[0])
print(csv_path)
print(json_path)
```

[image]